# Unable to play music from phone through PC?

Tags: windows, caching, usb, playback, mtp

Recently I lost the ability to play music from my phone through the PC connected through a USB cable. I don't recall exactly what I have changed by my player is using Foobar2000.

Initally Windows 8.1 would prompt me saying the FLAC file does not have a program to open it. Fair enough, I proceeded to set foobar as the default player.

However, double clicking the .flac file explorer.exe does not do anything. Strangely, there isn't an "open" option in the drop down menu when right click it either.

Windows seem unable to cache the audio file like it used to be able to. I am unsure if this is a service or an application issue and would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

If it helps, I'm using a Note3 with MTP USB 3.0 (Unchanged since the last time).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround by clicking on the open button on the ribbon header instead.